# SSRS Report not Rendering in IE 11 when user agent string is Default

Tags: reporting-services, internet-explorer-11, ssrs-2012

My SSRS Report is working Fine in other browsers but in IE11 when user agent string is "Default" , the report is not rendering in report viewer and it is just Loading Report.When i changed the user agent string to "Internet explorer 10" its working fine.This happens with the reports having charts.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem.
Add this in global.ascx file.

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim pathQuery = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery
    Dim url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower()

    If pathQuery.StartsWith("/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd") And Not url.Contains("iteration") Then

        Dim resourceStreamId = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("ResourceStreamId")

        If IsNothing(resourceStreamId) Then
            Return
        End If

        If resourceStreamId.ToString().Equals("blank.gif", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            Context.RewritePath(String.Concat(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "&IterationId=0"))
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```